# Bracket notation in SSJS (in the Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs

I have a script that is retrieving rows from a data extension and then looping through said rows.

The data extension is coming from a SF report so I can't edit the column names without copying it to another DE using SQL (which feels roundabout/clunky).

My issue is that I have a column with a space but bracket notation isn't working.

Here's the snippet of code that is causing the script to fail:

```
 var Record_ID = "";

 // get list of records
  var de = DataExtension.Init("Data_Extension_Name");
  var data = de.Rows.Retrieve();

  // Loop through the result set captured in the 'data' object
  for ( i in data )  {

Record_ID = data[i]["Record: ID"];
          if (Record_ID !== "") {
```

Record_ID = data[i]["Record: ID"]; is the offending line.

If I attempt the same script but use a field with no spaces or brackets (EX: data[i].Status) then it's fine.

I have tried the below combos and nothing has worked:

```
 Record_ID = data[i]["Record: ID"];

 Record_ID = data[i].[Record: ID];

 Record_ID = data[i]['Record: ID'];
```

Usually brackets work for fields with spaces but the SSJS doesn't seem to like brackets following data[i].

I even made a dummy variable and tried using that.

```
var Record_ID = "";
 var test = "Record: ID";

     // get list of records
      var de = DataExtension.Init("Data_Extension_Name");
      var data = de.Rows.Retrieve();

      // Loop through the result set captured in the 'data' object
      for ( i in data )  {

    Record_ID = data[i].test;
              if (Record_ID !== "") {
```

Will I really have to use SQL to rename the fields and copy all the data to a second DE??

Answer (score 1):

I tried with `data[i]['Record: ID']` and it's work without any issue.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var Record_ID = "";
    var de = DataExtension.Init("DataExtension External Key");
    var data = de.Rows.Retrieve();

      for ( i in data ){
      Write(data[i]['Record: ID']);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you fr the feedback! It didn't seem to execute even with data[i]['Record: ID'] for me so I ended up using a SQL interaction to just rename the field names.